# In SQL server, to convert a varchar which have this format (nnn:nn:nn)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this varchar format as time accumulation and i want to convert it to an integer to do a SUM and get the total time for a group. The fist part which may be 1, 2, 3, 4 or even five digits represent the accumulation of Hours and then seperated by a colon. then come the second part which is accumulation of minutes and last accumulation of seconds (2 digits each). How to convert this to integer in one query if possile.

Comment: can you post some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: How about storing numbers as number, not as strings? Three fields, one for hours, one for minutes, one for seconds? Think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- sample data for discussion
declare @T table (exceltime varchar(10));
insert @T select
'123:44:50' union all select
'3:44:50' union all select
'0:00:01' union all select
'1123:11:50';

-- This query breaks up your time into components
select
    stuff(exceltime,len(exceltime)-5,100,'') hr,
    left(right(exceltime,5),2) min,
    right(exceltime,2) second
from @T

-- and this one just adds them up
select
    60*60*stuff(exceltime,len(exceltime)-5,100,'') +
    60*left(right(exceltime,5),2) +
    right(exceltime,2) totalsecond
from @T


totalsecond         -- result
===============
445490
13490
1
4043510
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this query to retrieve the length of the span in seconds:

```
select sum(
    60*60*cast(left(span, len(span)-6) as int)
+   60*cast(substring(span, len(span)-4, 2) as int)
+   cast(right(span, 2) as int))
from test
```

The idea is to cut the parts to the left, to the right, and in the middle, multiply by the number of seconds in an hour and the number of seconds in a minute, and add the three components together.

Here is a link to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b33b7/21).